# Setting external CLK for a PIC

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mplab, mplabx, xc8

Using pic16f690 with xc8, I can't figure out how to set external `osc` with quartz crystal.

I have set :

```
#define FOSC_XT
```

Is that enough? Because I don't think it actually does something, I took out the xtal and the circuit still performs.

My configs:

```
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Selection bits (BOR enabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

 #define FOSC_XT
```

EDIT: Tried:

```
config FOSC = HS  //8MHZ
config FOSC = XT
```

Same results-when taking out the xtal the circuit runs as usual, or even starts without it. (At the speed of internal osc of 8mhz.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct.  You need to be setting the FOSC configuration bit as shown in REGISTER 14-1, page 174 of [this datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41262a.pdf).

You do not mention your crystal speed but this will make a difference, you might need HS, XT or LP.  The FOSC configuration bit can be set by specifying the correct value like below:

`#pragma config FOSC = XT  // use external crystal/resonator`

Comment: I actually did that after my post, exactly that line, and i can see that when i remove the xtal, the circuit still perform right, so i guess it didnt work ....

Comment: I am using 8mhz

Comment: i have also tried with HS mode , config FOSC = HS  and got the same result, so circuit runs without the xtal..

Comment: (talking about the timers-they runs in the same speed as when i used the internal osc)

Comment: You'll need to confirm that (1) the configuration #pragmas are correctly generated in the .hex file (2) your programmer is using them properly (and not using defaults) and (3) perhaps show us a diagram of how you have it hooked up.

Comment: See TABLE 17-1 (EXTERNAL CLOCK TIMING REQUIREMENTS) in the datasheet I linked to.  Regardless of your other problems you will need to use HS mode for an 8Mhz crystal.